# Hide dynamically created divs using its class names

Tags: jquery, html

I am dynamically creating divs by incrementing their class names. Now i have a close button on top right corner of the divs and i want a particular div to hide when i click on close button.

**Code:**

```
var i=1;
var newImageBoxdiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({ class:"demo"+i, id:"image"});
newImageBoxdiv.innerHTML = "<img id='MyImage' />";   
newImageBoxdiv.insertAfter('.demo');
i++;
$('#CloseWindow').click(function(){
?????
});
```

Everytime i create a div. I get its class name as demo1,demo2... and so on. What should i write in #CloseWindow function to hide the div i want to?

Comment: You are creating invalid markup, IDs must be unique. Also note that class is a reserved word in JavaScript, you should wrap it with quotation marks.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the image onto the div dynamically. So i cant change the id's because each time i am calling this `document.getElementById("image").innerHTML="<img id='MyImage' src='"+d+"'/>";` from another function. I do not know how do you do this same using class name?

Comment: Since you are already using jquery, you can use $('.classname') in the other function to select all divs with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(divSelector).hide()` will hide the element selected

`$(divSelector).show()` will show the element selected

`$(divSelector).toggle()` will toogle show/hide on the element selected

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a `.live()` function to make sure the click binding happens on dynamically generated content.

```
$('#CloseWindow').live('click', function(){ 
    $(divSelector).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, when you create the div, i would use the incrementer on the id, not the class since id is unique:

```
var newdiv = $('div id="demo' + i + '" class="demo">')
```

secondly, you need to skip the id in the imagetag, or use the same logic there, since you are getting alot of divs created i assume.

```
newdiv.append($('<img class="myimage" />')); //this will add myimage to end of newdiv
```

Now in closewindow you can close by using classname.

```
$('#closewindow').click(function(){
    $('.demo').hide();
});
```